# Is this a known function on partitions?

Tags: co.combinatorics

During a calculation, I have met a function on partitions, $F(\lambda)$, which seems to evaluate to positive integers. I have a procedure for computing it, but I was hoping for a formula, so I thought I would put the numbers here in case someone has seen them before or has a good guess.

I had no luck with the OEIS.

For the smallest partitions, which is all I can compute really, the function is:

\begin{array}{|l|l|}
\hline
\lambda   & F(\lambda) \\ \hline
(1)         & 1            \\ \hline
(2)         & 1            \\ \hline
(1,1)       & 1            \\ \hline
(3)         & 4            \\ \hline
(2,1)       & 3            \\ \hline
(1,1,1)     & 1            \\ \hline
(4)         & 20           \\ \hline
(3,1)       & 16           \\ \hline
(2,2)       & 5            \\ \hline
(2,1,1)     & 6            \\ \hline
(1,1,1,1)   & 1            \\ \hline
(5)         & 148          \\ \hline
(4,1)       & 100          \\ \hline
(3,2)       & 60           \\ \hline
(3,1,1)     & 40           \\ \hline
(2,2,1)     & 25           \\ \hline
(2,1,1,1)   & 10           \\ \hline
(1,1,1,1,1) & 1            \\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Does $(6)$ give $1348$?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.findstat.org/?

Comment: But anyways I just checked with the data you provided and as far as I can see it did not find any matches...

Comment: @PeterTaylor sadly (6) is outside my computing capability. Do you have a guess?

Comment: Maybe if you post the procedure, it can be optimised. I was speculating that the function applied to partitions into one part might correspond to [OEIS A001171](https://oeis.org/A001171).

Comment: excuse stating the obvious: the sum seems to be https://oeis.org/A000165.  So it might be a map from signed permutations to integer partitions in disguise.

Comment: @Marcel in any case, it would be great if you could add the definition of your function to findstat!

Comment: 123456789 ping?